# Where to install jdk 9.0.4 in Ubuntu?

Tags: java

I want to learn Java. I downloaded the tarbull file from oracle's website. [It's currently in my Download folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIlMv.png). The IDE I'm going to use is intelliJ where I've liberty to choose the JDK location. But I'm lil bit confuse where should I install it?

Comment: In general you should install software from the Ubuntu's repositories instead of downloading them from a website.

Answer (score 0):

The installation procedure for older versions of the JDK still applies if the version numbers are adjusted: https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/799387

On the other hand, you can install `openjdk-9-jdk` from the repositories as a substitute for Oracle Java: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/openjdk-9-jdk